# What is the name for this type of description?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a name for when a writer refers to a character as "the old man" or "tall woman" instead of using a name? I feel like I've heard a writing term for it before, but I can't remember it

Comment: *Nameless* characters? :)

Comment: Yes, I think Justin’s answer is correct. I am not aware of any specific literary term for nameless characters characterized by physical description.

Comment: This could potentially be asked on either [literature.se] SE (which takes questions about literary terms and things used in existing writing) or [writers.se] SE.

Comment: I didn't even realise Literature SE existed

Answer (score 1):

> **characterise**
>
> verb
>
> ​
> ​: **to describe something by stating its main qualities**

Source: [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/characterize?topic=defining-and-explaining)